# Is it possible to use ontologies with CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, rdf

We have built an ontology and now we would like to store data using it, and we were wondering if it is possible to use CosmosDB for that ? I know it is possible to use CosmosDB to create and query graph databases thanks to the Gremlin API, but I haven't found anything that suggests it is possible to store data expressed with RDF in CosmosDB.

Comment: No, it doesn't. That means, you have to convert the RDF dataset into some format that CosomosDB is able to process.

Comment: you should vote for the feature: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/d5734c02-555b-ed11-a81b-000d3ae49307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my investigation, cosmos db only has 5 api so far : SQL API,Mongo API,Table API,Graph API(for apache gremlin) and Cassandra API. It doesn't support storing any data with RDF model.

If you do concern about whether ms has related plan, you could submit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to get official comment from ms team.

If your requirement is urgent,maybe you could get idea about [Amazon Neptune](https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/) which supports RDF model.

[image]